# How can I disable "slingshot" action in iOS gestures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm using a UIPanGesture to move a UITextView and a UIScrollView around on my screen. I only want them to move exactly where they are dragged. But it responds to a "pull down like a slingshot" or a swipe sort of gesture that sends the objects flying across the screen, out of view, and then they slowly drift back into their places within set boundaries. How can I disable these specific gestures? I only want a direct drag and place, no flying across the screen with a flick, swipe, or slingshot.

I'm writing in Objective-C...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the view that is the one moving, sounds like your scrollView, to  `scrollView.bounces = NO`. Should be one or more scrollViews (or class that inherits from UIScrollView. bounce property creating that effect, the default for this is YES, here is apple docs on UIScrollView's bounce property.
-bounces

Property
A Boolean value that controls whether the scroll view bounces past the edge of content and back again.

Declaration
SWIFT
var bounces: Bool
OBJECTIVE-C
@property(nonatomic) BOOL bounces
Discussion
If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view bounces when it encounters a boundary of the content. Bouncing visually indicates that scrolling has reached an edge of the content. If the value is NO, scrolling stops immediately at the content boundary without bouncing. The default value is YES.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't appear to change anything. When I drag or swipe in one direction, it slings it off in the opposite direction and then slowly drifts back into the boundaries. Maybe it has something to do with how I've set up my boundaries.